# How to play sound on select radio button option in Android

Tags: android

Here below string when user select on option ringtone play..

Strings to show in dialog with Radio Buttons:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Default", " Vibration", " Best awake ", " Elegent Ringtone " , "Digital phone"};
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Keep your sound files in an array. Define a array say "music" globally.

```
int[] music ;
```

2.Implement DialogInterface.OnClickListener in your activity(or fragment)

3.Initialize your sound res array and title array in OnCreate and create a single choice alert dialog

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Default", " Vibration", " Best awake ", " Elegent Ringtone " , "Digital phone"};
music = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",this);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose Sound");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,-1,this);
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
```

4.Your onCLick of DialogInterface.OnClickListener will look should look like this

```
 @Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position) {
  switch (position){
      case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE :
          //Do your stuffs
          dialogInterface.dismiss();
          break;
      case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
          //Do your stuffs
          dialogInterface.dismiss();
          break;
      default: //Single choice item selected
          playSound(music[position]);
          break;
  }
}
```

5.The playsound method will be something like this

```
private void playSound(int res) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,res);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```